# Java HttpServlet headers do not get set correctly when servlet is called multiple times in quick succession (concurrently)

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency

**Problem:** I have an HttpServlet (served from localhost:8080) that looks like this:

```java
@WebServlet(name = "ConcurrencyServlet", urlPatterns = { "/concurrency" })
  public class ConcurrencyServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

    String x = req.getParameter("x");
    writer.println("{\"module\":\"" + this.toString() + "\",\"value\":\"" + x + "\"}");
    writer.flush(); // This makes no difference, though
  }
}
```

And a javascript (served from localhost:9000) that calls it 10 times in quick succession, creating concurrency:

```js
(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $.getJSON('//localhost:8080/concurrency', { x: i }, function (data) {
      $('#out').append(data.module + ' : ' + data.value + '<br>');
    });
  }
})();
```

The problem is that I need a `Content-Type=application/json`- and an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*`-Header set and it is crucial that the content of the calls is not mixed up. The servlet seems not to handle the setting of headers and the access to the PrintWriter (`response.getWriter()`) very well, when concurrency occurres, though.

**Question:** Is there a way to configure HttpServlets to handle these simultaneous calls correctly?

Sincerely, Manuel

---

**Solution:** The error was in one of the filters. It stored the response in an instance-variable (which is not thread-safe). After moving the variable to the doFilter-method, the error is gone.

Comment: *The servlet seems not to handle ... very well* - What do you observe?

Comment: You are not using any mutable state in your `ConcurrencyServlet` thus there is no way there could be any concurrency issues to take place. just try doing a `writer.flush();` at the end.

Comment: @wero I get X-Origin-Errors on the client-side and the responses of the calls are mixed (some are empty and their content is transferred to another responses content.)

Comment: @shazin When I flush (or even close) the writer, the behaviour stays the same.

Comment: @zoku did you use the network view in your browser dev tools to verify that the server sends garbled content?

Comment: @wero Yes, that's where I first noticed that the content of the responses was like:
Resp A:
(empty)

Resp B:
foo
bar

When I requested: A: foo, B: bar

Comment: I also get Internal Server Errors (NullPointerException) sometimes.

Comment: Sometimes such as where?

Comment: @zoku What servlet container? Do you have any additional filters installed? Would be a good idea to include the NPE stacktrace in your question.

Comment: @wero I'm using Tomcat 7. The only filters I have installed are two filters setting the content type (urlPatterns *.html and *.json) and one which sets the Allowed-Origin to * and is configured to urlPattern /* and servlets=*.

Comment: The `NullPointerException` you've just posted does not come from this code. It comes from some JSP. Unclear what you're asking, and non-reproducable problem.

Comment: @zoku smells like a bug in Tomcat 7 but it has nothing todo with your servlet. Remove your error jsp, or debug the tomcat code or upgrade to a newer Tomcat version.

Comment: @wero It really was the Access-Header-Filter. I had the response cast to a HttpServletResponse to add the headers and the variable was an instance-variable. So the error occurred because I messed up the thread-safety of the construct in the filter, not the servlet itself. Your hint to look out for filters pushed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the error thanks to wero's hint to look out for filters.

There was a filter:

```java
@WebFilter(
                filterName = "AccessControlFilter",
                description = "Change access mathods, add headers to requests.",
                urlPatterns = { "/*" },
                servletNames = "*"
                )
public class AccessControlFilter implements Filter {
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        MyResponseWrapper wrapper = new MyResponseWrapper(response);

        wrapper.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        wrapper.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Changed it to:

```java
@WebFilter(
                filterName = "AccessControlFilter",
                description = "Change access mathods, add headers to requests.",
                urlPatterns = { "/*" },
                servletNames = "*"
                )
public class AccessControlFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        MyResponseWrapper wrapper = new MyResponseWrapper(response);

        wrapper.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        wrapper.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Now it works.